# Gwt- file path when uploading the file

Tags: gwt, file-upload

Here i have stucked in simple concept.How to get the file-path when uploading the file in GWT. For example-(d:/example.xls) this is my upload-file. how to get this path programmatically? i have tried this

```
FileUpload ff=New FileUpload();
ff.getFileName();
```

when i use above code.it is returning only example.xls only.. help me

Answer (score 0):

You can't access this information from GWT (and javascript in general)

Answer (score 0):

I think, you cannot get the absolute path of a file that you have uploaded. The path will be absent or changed to avoid security risks, after you have done the upload.

You can get the file's name using the getFileName() function,
 and even its content, with the HTML5 FileAPI.

Comment: thnks for the reply. Here i need to get the MsExcel-contents i am uploading one Excel file and i need to read the contents from that excel file .. how to do? can you help me